# De-spike u,v,w wind speed data and replace them with pad in Python

Tags: python, outliers

I try everything already, I searched results in stackover,  internet and I really stack or I just blind. I have an *csv IMU data (Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Magnetometer etc.) and I want to detect spikes that are 3sigma higher than median, what I already done, but what I can't do is to replace those outliers (spikes)  with the mean values of the values from two nearest raws. Please help ! For detecting outliers I used 3sigma rules insted of 1.5IQR as this method is more suitable for my data. Data are mostly negative. I don't want to remove spikes.

EDIT I've done something like this and it seems to work, but it replace outliers with median values and I want to replace them with mean of values from raw behind and in front of outliers raw.

```
`imu_var=['Accelerometer X','Accelerometer Y','Accelerometer Z','Gyroscope X','Gyroscope Y','Gyroscope Z','Magnetometer X','Magnetometer Y',
 'Magnetometer Z','Pitch','Roll','Yaw','Temperature','Heave']
imu_sigma=imu[imu_var].std()
imu_median=imu[imu_var].median()
lower_imu = (imu_median - 3 * imu_sigma)
upper_imu = (imu_median + 3 * imu_sigma)
imu2=np.where((imu[imu_var] > upper_imu) | (imu[imu_var] < lower_imu),imu_median,imu[imu_var])
imu_out=pd.DataFrame(imu2,columns=imu_var)
imu[imu_var]=imu_out[imu_var]
imu_out.describe()`
```

Comment: Code above removed the outliers but I want to detect them.

Answer (score 0):

first of all take a look here, Find peaks inside a signal based on peak properties. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

In you case you can try something [here](https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/data-analytics/how-to-find-outliers/):

```
def impute_outliers_IQR(df):

   q1=df.quantile(0.25)

   q3=df.quantile(0.75)

   IQR=q3-q1

   upper = df[~(df>(q3+1.5*IQR))].max()

   lower = df[~(df<(q1-1.5*IQR))].min()

   df = np.where(df > upper,

       df.mean(),

       np.where(

           df < lower,

           df.mean(),

           df

           )

       )

   return df
```

Comment: thank you. Today I am going to try find_peaks. Your code almost work. There is an error : operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16800,10) (8,) (16800,10). I looks like problem with the lower. Any ideas?

Comment: shapes (16800,10) (8,) (16800,10 ) since problem (Broadcasting) solved here: https://www.statology.org/operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes/